# Changing array in JavaScript function changes array outside of function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Why the two scripts behave differently? I want the to use the first script, but in the second `drawData()` call it changes `data`; it's weird and not what I want to happen. The second script does not have this problem. Why is it like that, and how can I fix the first script?

First script does not change `data`:

```js
    var data = ["right"];

    function drawData(arrs, type) {
        if (type == "percentage") {
            arrs[0] = "omg";
        }
        console.log(data[0]); // Changed!?
    }
    drawData(data);
    drawData(data, "percentage");
```

Second script:

```js
    var data = "right";

    function drawData(arrs, type) {
        if (type == "percentage") {
            arrs = "omg";
        }
        console.log(data); // OK, not changed.
    }
    drawData(data);
    drawData(data, "percentage");
```

Comment: It is because an object is itself. When an object is modified *that* object is modified. When a value (object) is passed to a function it is **not copied, cloned or duplicated** (internally there are different techniques that are used, but this is semantically correct). That is, there is only one array -- and that *same* array is changed inside the function. If you wish to be able to change it without fear of affecting the outside, make a copy first. For a simple array this can be done with `Array.prototype.slice`. Otherwise, libraries like jQuery have handy copy methods.

Comment: Oh, and answerees, **before you say** "pass by reference", please read [Evaluation strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) and search for the term "reference" in the [ECMAScript specification](http://es5.github.com/) and be able to back up your word choices. Thanks!

Comment: thank you, I've found something interesting in [http://stackoverflow.com/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)  just look at John Resig's answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is the difference between assignment to a local variable and mutation of the given object.

In both pieces of code `arrs` is a local variable, distinct from `data`. But the *elements* and other properties of `arrs` are exactly the same as those of `data`. Making changes to those property values (which is commonly called *mutation* of the object/array) will be visible whether you access them via `arrs` or via `data`. And this is exactly what the first script does.

The second script however, does not change a property value of `arrs`, but assigns an entirely new value to `arrs`, so that now it does not share any properties any more with `data`. This is even more apparent, because both `data` and `arrs` are primitive values which cannot mutate like explained in the previous paragraph. But even if they were objects or arrays, and you would do the following assignment:

```
arrs = [1234];
```

It would not affect `data`. `data` would only be affected if you would assign to a property/index of `arrs` without assigning to `arrs` directly.

Answer (score 0):

First variant modifies object passed as parameter to function (which happens to be array)  - so this change is seen outside function. Second variant  assigns new value to  function parameter (which happens to be reference to array) but does not change  array itself.

Comment: Response is too unclear/cryptic for this question and uses ill-defined terms: "changes reference to this array"? It also mixes up scope (assignment of a local variable) with object mutability (assignment of a property on an object).